# Is uncorrelated normal vector still independent even if covariance matrix is singular?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be a normal random vector with a mean vector $\mu$ and a covariance matrix $\Sigma$.
Suppose that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are uncorrelated, so that $\Sigma$ is diagonal.
If $\Sigma$ is positive definite, then $\mathbf{X}$ has density
$$f(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n\det\Sigma}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\mu)\right),$$
which splits into densities of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, showing that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent. But what if $\Sigma$ is not positive definite? If $\mathbf{X}$ has no density, how can I show that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are indepenent? Is it even true?

Comment: If $X_i$ were independent, then their covariance matrix would be diagonal, which immediately tells you that they cannot be independent if $\Sigma$ is not definite.

Comment: You still have diagonal $\Sigma$.  If $\Sigma_{ii}=0$ then $X_i$ is a point mass so is independent of everything else.  Remove that, rinse and repeat until you end up with a positive-definite $\Sigma$.

Comment: I see, thanks. Can you explain why point mass is independent of everything else?

Comment: @ashpool: For events, if $P(A)=1$ then $P(A,B)=P(B)=P(A)P(B)$ so you have independence from $A$ for any $B$ (and similarly  if $P(A)=0$ then $P(A,B)=0=P(A)P(B)$ so you also  have independence).  Just translate that into random variables.

Comment: @Henry I see. Thanks for the help!